# Invalid calling object on clearIntval()

Tags: javascript, html

I am getting an "Invalid calling object" when I call clearInterval, and I can't seem to figure it out.  This error is only happening on IE.  Here is my code.  Thank you.  Please let me know if more info is required.

```
<html>
<HEAD>
    <title>Loading, please wait...</title>
    <META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW"/>
    <script>    
    var ctr = 1;
    var ctrMax = 15; // how many is up to you-how long does your end page take?
    var intervalId;     
    function Begin() 
    {
      //set this page's window.location.href to the target page
        window.location.href = page.html;
        // but make it wait while we do our progress...
        intervalId = window.setInterval("ctr=UpdateIndicator(ctr, ctrMax)", 250);
    }   
    function End() {
    // once the interval is cleared, we yield to the result page (which has been running.  This is where it is breaking)

        window.clearInterval(intervalId);
    }

    function UpdateIndicator(curCtr, ctrMaxIterations) 
    {   

        curCtr += 1;            
        if (curCtr <= ctrMaxIterations) {
            document.getElementById("indicator").style.width =curCtr*25 +"px";
            return curCtr;
        }
        else 
        {
            document.getElementById("indicator").style.width =0;
            return 1;
        }
    }
    </script>
    <link rel="Stylesheet" href="styles/dynamic.css" type="text/css" />
</HEAD>
<body onload="Begin()" onunload="End()">
    <form id="Form1" method="post" runat="server">
        <div align="center">
            <h3>&nbsp;</h3>
            <H3>&nbsp;</H3>
            <H3>&nbsp;</H3>
            <H3>&nbsp;</H3>
            <H3>&nbsp;</H3>
            <H3>Loading Form, please wait...</H3>
        </div>
        <table id="indicator" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="0" height="19"
            align="center" class="title">
            <tr>
                <td align="center" width="100%"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Trying removing `window.` and just call `clearInterval`. You don't need the prefix

Comment: @RobM.: And yet that should make no difference.

Comment: @ user: There's no need to clear the timer when the page is unloading. Clearing the timer will be done for you as part of the page unloading, and there are all sorts of restrictions on what you're allowed to do during `onunload`, I couldn't swear you're not running into one of them. Separately: I strongly recommend *not* using strings with `setInterval` or `setTimeout`. But that wouldn't be why you're getting that odd error.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, Yeah I did try just removing it earlier, and everyrhting seemed to run as intended.  But, I was editing someone else's code and didn't want to do that unless I had to, but I probably will.  I noticed the string in setInterval as well haha.  Was going to change that too.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: i think you have error in the line     'window.location.href = page.html;' i have comment this line and try the same in IE, FIREFOX and CHROME.... Everything works fine...

Comment: The whole `Begin()` function doesn't make sense. Event if `page.html` had quotes, `window.location.href` would start to load a new page immediately, and the interval will be never created.

Comment: @Teemu: That is a very good point, I didn't look at what `Begin` was doing.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I'm aware that there is no difference b/w `window.clearInterval` and `clearInterval`, but it was worth a try given the specific error they were getting.